# How to apply the CSS of navbar-inverse in twitter-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

By using [twitter-bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar)
It will be possible to modify the look of the navbar by adding `.navbar-inverse`.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  ...
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is a simple js module to change the theme of the web site.
My script is just able to add a class to the body selector and then everything is made by the less file.

```
$('body').addClass('theme-dark');
```

By using js code it is quite easy to obtain the result.

```
$('.navbar').addClass('navbar-inverse');
```

But my question is different:
will it be possible just by adding the newTheme class to body selector to apply the navbar-inverse, changing the less file?
If yes how should I write the less rule?

I would like to make something like this:

```
.theme-dark {
    .navbar {
       // a function which makes
       // the style of navbar-inverse
```

Requirements:

I am using less for css, jquery and underscore.

Comment: Why don't you just use an alternate stylesheet?

Comment: @cimmanon thanks for your comment. What do you mean with an alternate stylesheet? can you give me an example? thanks

Comment: @cimmanon, to me your suggestion to use `alternate stylesheets` seems that does not fit my purpose. 1) bootstrap already give me the style about navbar-inverse... so why should I attach another css file? Maybe I didn't understand the `alternate stylesheets`. Thanks to clarify me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LESS provides the ability to use previously defined classes as mixins in other contexts. Try this:

```
.theme-dark {
    .navbar {
        .navbar-inverse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.navbar div{ padding: 0.2em;}
This solves the issue